# how to include javascript file and css file in wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, css, javascript

I am creating new plugin so i need add a java script file and css file.

These are my javascript files

1. jquery.min.js
2. jquery-1.3.2.min.js
3. jquery.tabify.js

Css file:

1. newstyle.css

Comment: why do you include jQuery twice?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38050537/1153703

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress already ships with jQuery.  There is no need to include it in your theme.

## Javascript

Let's say your `jquery.tabify.js` file is located in `/js/jquery.tabify.js` in your theme.  Include the following code in your `functions.php` file:

```
function jquery_tabify() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'jquery-tabify',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.tabify.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_tabify' );
```

This will include your script *and* jQuery.  jQuery is marked as a dependency, so it's loaded first.

If your file is instead hosted on a separate server, let's say as `http://site.com/jquery.tabify.js`, specify that as the path instead (omitting `get_template_directory_uri()`):

```
function jquery_tabify() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'jquery-tabify',
        'http://site.com/jquery.tabify.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_tabify' );
```

## CSS

You register styles the same way.  Assuming your file is located in `/css/newstyle.css`, add the following code to your `functions.php` file:

```
function add_newstyle_stylesheet() {
    wp_register_style(
        'newstyle',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/newstyle.css'
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'newstyle' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_newstyle_stylesheet' );
```